# Unable to cURL and then unzip file

Tags: bash, curl

I'm able to download a simple zip file using cURL (822mb), but when I try to unzip it in my bash script, I get the following error:

```
"error:  cannot open zipfile [ glove.6B.zip ]
        Permission denied"
```

If I run the script again, it apparently has permission to read the file, and it unzips the file successfully. Has anyone had encountered this type of error before?

Here's my script if you want to try replicating. I'm running macOS Sierra.

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p data
cd data
if [ ! -f glove.6B.100d.txt ]; then
    if ! openssl md5 glove.6B.zip | grep -q 056ea991adb4740ac6bf1b6d9b50408b; then
        curl -OL http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip
    fi
    echo "zip file present"
    echo "unzipping embeddings"
    unzip glove.6B.zip glove.6B.100d.txt
else
    echo "embeddings present"
fi
```

Comment: I tried your script and it works.

Comment: If I try running md5 on the file while it's being downloaded, I get a file permission error, but then my script completes successfully. Might be a problem with security software installed on my machine, I guess.